Why is a REST call from the same machine not resolving to localhost IP?
We have a legacy REST client which lives on both the app-server and other machines, which makes calls to the app-server with an URL like http://MY-APP-SERVER-NAME:1234/Endpoint.
In the ASP.net handler we want to check if the request has come from the local machine and have code like this in our controller:
[HttpPut, Route("/Endpoint")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Method()
{
    var sourceIp = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();

    if (sourceIp.Equals("0.0.0.1"))...

What we're observing is that userIpAddress is taking some unexpected value like 34.12.56.73. Both RemoteIpAddress and LocalIpAddress are the same IPv6 address configured for the local machine's virtual network adapter.
I wonder if the client should be making calls to localhost instead of MY-APP-SERVER-NAME but this code is harder to change.
It seems like it should be easy to tell if the request has come from the machine it is received on, is there some simple utility?

What does Wireshark say? What networks is the machine connected to?

Methinks the problem is you're using MapToIPv4() inappropriately here. You should only call MapToIPv4() when IsIPv4MappedToIPv6() returns true. Instead of all that, just test-for IPv4 and IPv6 localhost addresses separately because you cannot reliably normalize them down to IPv4.

As for where 34.12.56.73 is coming from - that seems to be from the bitshifting logic inside MapToIPv4. I'll post an answer shortly.

@Dai I wondered if I should be able to do if(Connection.RemoteIpAddress ==Connection.LocalIpAddress) but that seems too easy. What you write seems promising.

The solution:
Just use IPAddress.IsLoopback, it handles IPv4 and IPv6 correctly:
IPAddress remoteAddr = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

if( IPAddress.IsLoopback( remoteAddr ) )
{
    // 
} 


The rest...

Every OS I'm aware-of will prefer using IPv6 over IPv4 when both are available, this includes Windows - and applies to localhost / local-loopback connections.
...which means HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress could be either an IPv4 or IPv6 address.
...which means using .MapToIPv4() on RemoteIpAddress here is incorrect.

The .MapToIPv4() method is only for use when an IPv4 address has been mapped into IPv6 space and it needs to be mapped back - which is a lossy operation that just chops-off all but the last 6 octets of IPAddress' internal representation.



Visually, here's IPv4 compared to IPv6, as a sequence of octets:
Octet  |   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
       |
IPv4   |  00 11 22 33                                      // 0.17.34.51
IPv6   |  00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF  //

When passing an IPv6 address into MapToIPv4(), the method rearranges octets 12 through 15, sets octets 10 and 11 to FF and drops (zeroes-out) all preceding octets, like so:
Octet  |   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
       |
Input  |  00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF
Output |                                FF FF DD CC FF EE // 221.204.255.238

Now you said you saw the output of MapToIPv4() was an address like 34.12.56.73, which is 22 0C 38 49, and we can map that back so we can see the last 4 octets of the original IPv6 address was 0C 22 49 38 - with the other 12 bytes being anyone's guess - but it isn't 00 00 00 01 which we'd expect to see with ::1.
...but you say:

Both RemoteIpAddress and LocalIpAddress are the same IPv6 address configured for the local machine's virtual network adapter.

...I'm going to assume that these are IPv6 Link-Local addresses then (those FE 80 ... addresses, because the rightmost octets of IPv6 Link-Local addressses are often chosen at random by the OS.
(...but that still shouldn't be happening for an ostensible localhost loopback connection, even if the hostname is a different DNS label - but maybe the fact you have a "virtual network adapter" means that something is going on?)
...in which case your code should check-for Link-Local addresses, but be careful because Link-Local addresses can also be used for other hosts directly-connected to your machine (whether physically or in a VM virtual network switch) - as well as testing to see if remoteAddr is the same as localAddr.
...so let's patch that address comparison logic:
The solution... improved:
IPAddress remoteAddr = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
IPAddress localAddr  = request.HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;

Boolean definitelyLocal             = IPAddress.IsLoopback( remoteAddr );
Boolean maybeLocal                  = remoteAddr.IsIPv6LinkLocal && localAddr.IsIPv6LinkLocal;
Boolean thisShouldNotNormallyHappen = remoteAddr.Equals( localAddr );

if( definitelyLocal || maybeLocal || thisShouldNotNormallyHappen )
{
    // 
}

...I named that last-one thisShouldNotNormallyHappen because normally when a socket's local and remote addresses are the same it's in listening mode. But I don't know your network config so anything's possible, I guess.

You could try this below code which will help you check if the request is from local machine or not:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net;

namespace LocalRequestChecker.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class LocalRequestChecker : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPut, Route("/Endpoint")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Method()
        {
            var remoteIp = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
            var localIp = HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress;

            // Check if the request is coming from the local machine
            if (IsLocalRequest(remoteIp, localIp))
            {
                return Ok("Request is from local machine.");
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized("Request is not from local machine.");
            }
        }

        private bool IsLocalRequest(IPAddress remoteIp, IPAddress localIp)
        {
            // Check if the remote IP is the same as the local IP
            if (remoteIp.Equals(localIp))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // Check if the remote IP is a loopback address
            if (IPAddress.IsLoopback(remoteIp))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
}

Test result:


The issue you were facing because of the use of IPv6 addresses or NAT configurations that complicate this comparison. so batter to check  IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses. as some time the IP address might be in IPv6 format even if it's a local request.
